# Rails 5 allowing a JSON field through strong parameters not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to let through a deeply nested JSON field in my model (document => field_instance => value). I was using an empty hash due to a misunderstanding of the [documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

permit! can do what I need but I am trying to avoid simply doing `params.fetch(:document).permit!` due to the massive security hole this opens. So how can I permit any structures of any type under the doubly nested JSON value 'parameter' only?

I am testing with a single string under value called text, and am getting 'Unpermitted parameter: text'

Each instance_field has a specific type which has a list of required parameters, but without a way of being specific for each instance_field in the document, I've opted just to allow all parameters under that JSON field.

Here is my document_params method:

```
params.fetch(:document)
  .permit(:structure_id, :field_instances_attributes => [
    :value, 
    :document_id, 
    :field_id, 
    :value_attributes => {}
  ])
```

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Or, even better: each field_instance has a type that knows the exact structure the field's value expects. Can I be specific about the fields allowed under value for each field_instance?

Related logs:

```
service_1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"Ô£ô", "authenticity_token"=>" -- censored --", "document"=>{"structure_id"=>"1", "field_instances_attributes"=>[{"document_id"=>"0", "field_id"=>"1", "value_attributes"=>{"text"=>"asdf"}}]}, "commit"=>"Create Document"}
service_1  | Unpermitted parameter: text
service_1  | Unpermitted parameter: text
service_1  | #<FieldInstance id: nil, field_id: 1, document_id: nil, value: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to build a params hash in multiple steps, but it's a little non-obvious.

Here's what I do:

```
def document_params
  @document_params ||= params.require(:document).permit(:structure_id, field_instance_atributes: %i[document_id field_id]).tap do |doc|
    doc[:value] = params[:document].require(:value).permit!
  end
end
```

If the `value` object sanitization is really complicated, perhaps write that as its own helper and use it here.

The important part is the use of `require`: it returns the inner value as a new object, and so manipulations against it don't affect `params`. You can go back to the well, so to speak, as many times as you need.

Caveat: `require` will throw `ActionController::ParameterMissing` if the key is not found.